# WebHooks Jira Service Managements

Tags: c#, jira, integration

I'm writing a post here because I'm having trouble integrating the jira webhook, my local app.
The thing is that if I create a new issue from my application, an issue is created in jira, but if I create an issue in jira, i.e. a new issue, the query is not executed, i.e. it does not create an issue in my local application, and I have mapped basic data such as:

```
public class JiraWebhookData{ 
public string WebhookEvent { get; set; } 
public string Key { get; set; } 
public string Summary { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string DueDate { get; set; } 
public JiraUser Reporter { get; set; } 
public JiraUser Assignee { get; set; } 
public Status Status { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; } 
public JiraIssue Issue { get; set; } 
public JiraUser User { get; set; }   

public virtual string GetDefaultInput()
     {
         return new JiraIssueRequest().ToJson(Formatting.Indented);
     }
 }
```

and here is my code:

```
public class Action : EntityActionBase 
{
    private JiraWebhookData _input;
 
    private readonly EntityService _entityService;
   
  public override void ExecuteAction()
     {
         _input = GetInputFromJson<JiraWebhookData>(EntMeta.DllActionOnAfterSaveInput);

         if (EntityActionType != EntityActionType.OnSave)
                 throw new ExtException("Incorrect action type configuration - OnAfterSave  action");

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntityDataJuice.GetParamValue<string>(_input.Summary)))
             throw new ExtException("Invalid value in Summary parameter");

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntityDataJuice.GetParamValue<string>(_input.Description))))
             throw new ExtException("Wrong value in Description parameter");
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntityDataJuice.GetParamValue<string>(_input.DueDate))))
             throw new ExtException("Incorrect value in DueDate");

         var issueDataFromForm = new JiraWebhookData
         {
             Summary = _input.Summary,
             Description = _input.Description,
             Assignee = _input.Assignee,
             DueDate = _input.DueDate
         };

         EntityDataJuice.AddParamValue("Summary", issueDataFromForm.Summary);
         EntityDataJuice.AddParamValue("Description", issueDataFromForm.Description);
         EntityDataJuice.AddParamValue("DueDate", issueDataFromForm.DueDate);

         string jsonData = "";
         ProcessJiraWebhookData(jsonData);

     }

     private void ProcessJiraWebhookData(string jsonData)
     {
         try
         {
             var eventData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JiraWebhookData>(jsonData);

             if (eventData.WebhookEvent == "issue_created")
               {
                 var summary = eventData.Summary;
                 var description = eventData.Description;
                 var dueDate = eventData.DueDate;

                 // Create a request in your application based on data from Jira
                 var issueDataFromJira = new EntityDataJuice(); // Set the correct entity name
                 issueDataFromJira.SetParameter("Summary", summary);
                 issueDataFromJira.SetParameter("Description", description);
                 issueDataFromJira.SetParameter("DueDate", dueDate);

                 _entityService.SaveFromJuice(issueDataFromJira);

             }
             else
             {
                 throw new Exception("Could not download data");
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             throw new Exception("Error processing Jira webhook: " + ex.Message);
         }
     }
 }
```

}

Can anyone help me, I'm very pressed for time.
thanks for any help!

I tried to send via postman but it keeps throwing me a strange error that the browser does not support the query, and if it executes the query via ``https://pipedream.com/
it works fine but it doesn't write back i.e. it doesn't save me my data in my local application